# Is there a Dropdown component which allows for a custom styled options on desktop, but native behavior on mobile?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, select, dropdown

Which component could I use in order to have a `<select>` dropdown with custom styled `<option>` elements on desktop, but be able to maintain the native behavior on mobile?

From what I'm seeing, the `<option>` element has limited styling (only `background-color`, `font-size` and `color` seem to be working).

Some styled dropdowns I've tried, like `bootstrap-select`, `react-select` or `react-styled-select` replace the `<option>` element with `<div>` or `<span>` in order to style it easier, but this across all resolutions, thus not being able to have the native behavior on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like there is at least one such dropdown:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/styleselect

It's a vanilla JS component which replaces the native `<select><option>` tags with `<div>`s on desktop, and leaves them native on mobile using this condition:

```
// Use native selects (which pop up large native UIs to go through the options ) on iOS/Android
if ( navigator.userAgent.match( /iPad|iPhone|Android/i ) ) {
    return
}
```